# How can add intell-ipp to qt 5.9

Tags: c++, windows, qt, intel-ipp

How can i add intel ipp in Qt 5.9 in windows?
at this time i add some path to .pro file

but
i See this Error :

```cpp
    IntelIPPlibs = -lippcc -lippccmt -lippch -lippchmt -lippcore -lippcoremt -lippcv -lippcvmt -lippdc -lippdcmt -lippi -lippimt -lipps -lippsmt -lippvm -lippvmmt

    #   Set the intel path based upon the platform.
    ThirdPartyLibraryPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.207\windows'
    win32: IntelIPPPath = $${ThirdPartyLibraryPath}/ipp
    linux: IntelIPPPath = $${ThirdPartyLibraryPath}/ipp

    win32 {
    DEFINES += WINNT
    LIBS += -L$$IntelIPPPath/lib/intel64 $$IntelIPPlibs
    }

    unix {
    DEFINES += LINUX
    LIBS += -L$$IntelIPPPath/lib/intel64 $$IntelIPPlibs
    }

    INCLUDEPATH += $${IntelIPPPath}/include
```

error: undefined reference to `ippInit@0'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: "How can i add intel ipp in Qt 5.9" - While *I* think I know what you talking about there, not all readers may. Your question should make clear what "ipp" and "qt" is (and more). When asking a question, please don't make assumptions about what your readers may know and explain any acronyms and special terminology used. Make it easy for people to understand your question and help you.

Comment: See also [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058) (possible duplicate).

Comment: Try [Adding Kit](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html) MSVC2017 64bit.